# Where can I find actual play posts and podcast for Exalted?

Tags: exalted, session-summaries

As the title says I am looking for exalted actual play podcasts and texts. My preference is something I can listen to but text is also welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request for a shopping list to offsite resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rpg.net has a bunch of [Exalted actual play threads](http://forum.rpg.net/search.php?searchid=1167568) you might be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I can only recommend https://www.rpnation.com/ for this. It has an active community of role-players and Exalted seems to be one of their most common Dice based systems recruiting.

It's simultaneously a good play to join an Exalted Play By Post, read through one for Ideas, and message veteran Exalted Players or STs with questions.

Comment: That sounds more like a place to go and play, rather than a place to watch or listen to.

Comment: It is both actually. While I will admit they're low on podcasts, there are a multitude of Play by Post threads going on of almost every splat (no real love for Mountain Folk or Dragonkings among the Fans of Second Ed, I'm sorry to say).

Comment: OK, I think your answer would be a very good one if you edit it to include, basically, what you just said in your comment. (If you are unaware, this site may be quite different from those you are used to, and one aspect of that is that comments are inherently ephemeral and temporary. Check out the [Tour] if you haven’t for more on how this site is different.)

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a podcast about an exalted game, summarizing their experience in Exalted 3rd Edition. The Campaign is called "Princes of the Universe" and can be found partly [on the Onyx Path Forum](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/exalted/777022-ex3-actual-play-exalted-princes-of-the-universe) and as audio files on http://atrusilk.podbean.com/

Some of their game documentation is also available in a [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oaWvJ4aJ68g2L405ccyPz6cJ82UKQoGG-w9Yl6J1byY/edit), however this also tells us, that at some point ( I am not sure when as I am still in episode 4), they transitioned to an other system. From the chart available on the google doc, I can estimate it is somewhere in the area of session 25.